# Linking Facebook like, to an image (from my website)

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have got a little problem here. Don't know if this is possible at all.

In short: i want to display the same Facebook like button that is connected to an image, on my website, and be able to click the like button to like the image, from my website.

I have tried to use various links and would appreciate any help with this!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got a Like button from facebook , I have a page there go to its admin panel, then from the sidebar there is a link named as resources. go to that page you will find like button there
Thanks,
Shah Rukh

Comment: Don't understand where you go on your facebook page to get the link, could you explain?

Comment: okay, I am giving you a direct link from where you can get the like button code, as i hade for my site. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/ just go to the link and then go to like likebox and grab the code for your website.

Comment: Yeah, i have played around with that a bit but i don't know how to get the link to a photo.

Comment: If you saved it in the database then you can get the link, I have a wordopress site, when i used the link for the like button it will share the post to my wall with its featured image.